# Submitting form after using e.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that I am stopping from submitting with e.preventDefault(). (I've also tried return false).

I would manually tell the form to submit after a short delay, using the code:

```
$('form').delay(2000).submit();
```

Unfortunately, e.preventDefault() seems to disable the form from submitting even if it explicitly submitted using the `submit()` function.

Any idea how I can combine these intentions? I'd like to show a loading screen for a couple of seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: I think `delay()` is only used for effects, not events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("form").on('submit.blocker', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("form").off('submit.blocker').trigger('submit');
    }, 2000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hmmm .. Still doesn't work for me (using Chrome, if that matters). Even with the most basic implementation, it only submits if I click the button twice (because `off('submit')` detaches the original handler). Any ideas why?

Comment: @ChrisNolet updated my answer with a possible solution: namespace the event handler names so only this specific one is unbound

Comment: Strange ... Ok, so that still doesn't work. But interestingly, even the most basic implementation of: `$('#myform').submit();` doesn't work, however `$('.submit').click()` does! So the problem is in that, rather than the e.preventDefault() code. Not sure why it's happening though.

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of your code then, and I'll see if I can help

Comment: All good - figured it out. There's a bug in jQuery: if you set your submit button with an id of 'submit', `$.submit()` stops working. Problem solved! Thanks for your time and answer! Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var okToSubmit = false;
        $('form').submit(function (e)
        {
            if ( ! okToSubmit)
            {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $form = $(this);
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    okToSubmit = true;
                    $form.submit();
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<form action="somewhere">
    <input type="text" name="something" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Above code is tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!e.isTrigger) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("form").trigger('submit');
        }, 2000);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try this it works for me:

```
<form name="demo" action="111" onSubmit="fun();return false">
<input type="text" name="name1" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and in the javascript

```
fun()
{
var x= document.forms["demo"];
setTimeout(x.submit(),2000);//time in milliseconds
}
```