# Prevent webpage from scrolling to the top when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have created a form that submits via javascript but each time I submit the form the webpage scrolls to the top. How do I stop that from happening?. I have tried preventDefault() but that stops the form from submitting all together.

My form:

```
class myform(forms.Form):
columns = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, label=False)

def __init__(self, columnList, *args, **kwargs):
    self.columnList = columnList
    super(myform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['columns'].widget = forms.SelectMultiple()
    self.fields['columns'].choices = self.columnList
```

My HTML:

```
<p> Select tables and download as excel file:</p>
<form id="myform" method="POST" name="Tables_selected">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }} 
<input id="mybutton" type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Download excel" onclick="redirect()"> 
</form>`
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
    $('#id_columns').change(function(){
        $('#myform').submit();
        return false;
    });
});
function redirect() {
    location.href="{% url 'download_excel'  %}";
}
</script>
```

I have tried this, but it prevents the form from being submitted, as well as the redirect:

```
    $(function(){
    $('#id_columns').change(function(){
        $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            );
    });

});
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363838/submit-form-after-calling-e-preventdefault

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps?